# Local site hits error: ValueError: Invalid hash method 'sha256'. but replit and render sites work fine

Tags: sha256

I have a site that was built in replit and also hosted in render. I finally tried to run locally and werkzeug.security library thows error: ValueError: Invalid hash method 'sha256'. All three sites hit a planetscale db to get the password. Local is a windoes box so I tried installing on AWS linux server too and still get the same error. Any idea what replit and render do that I'm not?

```
#error here:
      if check_password_hash(user.password_hash, form.password_hash.data):
        login_user(user)
```

Not sure what to try.

Comment: This is a Flask/Werkzeug 3.0  vs. 2.3.2/2.3.3 issue. Still searching how to resolve for 3.0 and rolled back to 2.x and all is good.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any way to change the hash method to other than SHA256? A message I receive from the library suggests "scrypt".

We run neither Linux nor AWS but experience the same issue with Python+Flask. I can run our system with Python 3.11.4 but got the warning:

```
The 'sha256' password method is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 3.0. Migrate to the 'scrypt' method.
```

My colleague runs Python 3.12 and experiences the error mentioned in the question (invalid hash method).